# cypher match query merge result set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm newer in CQL anyone help me to solve query to find list of followers with a flag if i also follow him. i'm trying like this way

```
MATCH (n:users_master)-[r:FOLLOW]->(m:users_master)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:users_master)<-[r2:FOLLOW]-(m:users_master)   
CASE when EXISTS(r2) THEN n.flag= 1 ELSE n.flag=0 END  
where id(m)=35  
RETURN n
```

notice here i'd also like to add a virtual property flag in result set LIKE `{"updated_at":"12/26/2016, 3:45:38 PM",
"created_on":"12/26/2016, 3:45:38 PM",
"last_name":"john",
"first_name":"john",
"email":"new@test",
"facebook_id":"12341",
"status":"Active",
"id":35
"flag":1
}`

Comment: The relationship in your OPTIONAL MATCH has arrows on both ends, you may want to fix that up. Also, instead of 1 and 0, would a boolean return work for you? That can be done extremely easily.

Comment: sorry arrow this is mistaken i removed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EXISTS() function can be used to check for the existence of a pattern, and in your case can replace your OPTIONAL MATCH.

Also, variables in your patterns aren't needed if you aren't going to be using them, so you shouldn't need them on your relationships at all.

```
MATCH (n:users_master)-[:FOLLOW]->(m:users_master)
WHERE id(m)=35  
RETURN n, EXISTS( (n)<-[:FOLLOW]-(m) ) as flag
```

'flag' will be a separate column with a boolean on whether or not the follow is reciprocal.

As far as adding a 'virtual property', in Neo4j 3.1+, you can use [Map Projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#_map_projection) to add custom values to the map projection of returned nodes.

You could use this query with map projection to include the flag in the return of node properties:

```
MATCH (n:users_master)-[:FOLLOW]->(m:users_master)
WHERE id(m)=35  
RETURN n {.*, flag: EXISTS( (n)<-[:FOLLOW]-(m) ) }
```

EDIT

The map projection used in the query above was introduced and only works in Neo4j 3.1.x and up.

For versions 3.0.x, I don't believe there are many options for extracting all node properties to a map and adding a new value to that map before returning (SET clause is reserved for nodes, not maps).

You may need to install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) for a workaround, as it provides several helper procedures and functions, including [map operations](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions).

This should work after the relevant version of APOC is added to your Neo4j instance:

```
MATCH (n:users_master)-[:FOLLOW]->(m:users_master)
WHERE id(m)=35  
RETURN apoc.map.setKey(properties(n), 'flag', EXISTS( (n)<-[:FOLLOW]-(m) )) as n
```

Comment: Also just want to note, usage of lookup by neo4j node ID is not recommended, as ids are reclaimed and reused as nodes are deleted. This means, if nodes or relationships are deleted in neo4j, and the id is reused for a different node, then systems outside of neo4j where you're storing that id may go out of sync with where that id is pointing to now. It's recommended to use your own unique ids on your nodes if needed, such as a UUID.

Comment: thanks Falcon but this is not working in neo4j >3. have you any alternative ?

Comment: This will work in Neo4j 3.1.x and up. Versions 3.0.x do not have the map projection feature. You'll probably need to use APOC Procedures as a workaround. I updated my answer with this alternate solution.